# How to prove that if a formal system L(f, T) is functionally complete, then also L(f, not) is?

Tags: logic

More precisely prove the following:

For all logical functions f if L(f, T) is functionally complete, then also L(f, not) is.

T refers to "logical true" here.

Comment: You have to prove that in the second case we can define $\top$.

Comment: Intuitively, in order to pe complete $\text L (\text f, \top)$ must be able to define a formula that is always Fasle (otherwise it is not complete). Call it $\bot$; the we have simply to define $\top = \lnot \bot$.

Comment: I am sorry, I specified my problem with it too vaguely. I know what it means and how to do it intuitively. But I seem to be unable to prove that I am able to form False or True in the second case.

Comment: But you **are** able to produce False in the first case by hypotheses, because $\text L(\text f, \top)$ is *functionally complete* .

Comment: Sorry, if i am missing something obvious, but how does it imply that we can produce True (or False) in the second case? I mean there is definitely a way to express False in the first formal system, but the way we express it might include True somewhere (something like $F = f(A,T, B, A, T, T)$ where A, B are boolean variables. And since we haven't got $T$ in the second case, we get nothing.